# Jmeter Ultimate thread group - Populating the user details from a csv

Tags: jmeter, threadgroup

I am trying to replay production logs where the User count varies every second. Currently, I am using Jmeter - Ultimate thread group where we can definethe user scenario. Is there a way, we can populate the user details(Number of Users, Initial delay, etc) from a csv file into the ultimate thread group (I may need to fill in for abt an hour).

Thanks,
Praveen

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's possible by adding a "CSV Data Set Config" to your thread group - although I'm not sure how to loop through the csv values in one table.

But the easier way (as hinted at in the [Ultimate Thread Group docs](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/)) is to add threads_schedule to your user.properties file.  Just add to the last line

```
threads_schedule=\
spawn(15,1s,1s,1s,1s) \
spawn(40,1s,3s,1s,2s)
```

You could use a special file you load on jMeter startup, using a -q UTG.properties commandline argument.  The backslashes escape the newlines, so it's almost like csv - you could export a csv from excel and do a pretty simple find and replace to add spawn( and )\ to the beginning and end of each line.